# Problem installing Eclipse Hono - No resource found in hono namespace

Tags: eclipse-hono

We are having some trouble installing Eclipse Hono on CentOS 8. We are following the official [getting started guide](https://www.eclipse.org/hono/getting-started/) and it seems to be running, but the step to verify the installation keeps failing and we can't access Hono as described in the guide.

After following the installation steps, `kubectl get svc` gives us the output

```
NAME                                    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                           AGE
hono-adapter-amqp-vertx                 LoadBalancer   10.99.108.43     <pending>     5672:32672/TCP,5671:32671/TCP     13d
hono-adapter-amqp-vertx-headless        ClusterIP      None             <none>        <none>                            13d
hono-adapter-http-vertx                 LoadBalancer   10.107.96.191    <pending>     8080:30080/TCP,8443:30443/TCP     13d
hono-adapter-http-vertx-headless        ClusterIP      None             <none>        <none>                            13d
hono-adapter-mqtt-vertx                 LoadBalancer   10.105.254.109   <pending>     1883:31883/TCP,8883:30883/TCP     13d
hono-adapter-mqtt-vertx-headless        ClusterIP      None             <none>        <none>                            13d
hono-artemis                            ClusterIP      10.111.168.4     <none>        5671/TCP                          13d
hono-dispatch-router                    ClusterIP      10.101.138.249   <none>        5673/TCP                          13d
hono-dispatch-router-ext                LoadBalancer   10.97.82.10      <pending>     15671:30671/TCP,15672:30672/TCP   13d
hono-grafana                            ClusterIP      10.107.11.66     <none>        3000/TCP                          13d
hono-prometheus-server                  ClusterIP      10.106.38.193    <none>        9090/TCP                          13d
hono-service-auth                       ClusterIP      10.106.176.56    <none>        5671/TCP                          13d
hono-service-auth-headless              ClusterIP      None             <none>        <none>                            13d
hono-service-device-registry            ClusterIP      10.107.84.53     <none>        5671/TCP,8443/TCP                 13d
hono-service-device-registry-ext        LoadBalancer   10.110.10.95     <pending>     28080:31080/TCP,28443:31443/TCP   13d
hono-service-device-registry-headless   ClusterIP      None             <none>        <none>                            13d
kubernetes                              ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                           13d
```

However, the command `kubectl get service -n hono` that the [Helm chart readme](https://github.com/eclipse/packages/blob/master/charts/hono/README.md) suggests for verifying the installation fails with "No resource found in hono namespace". There is definitely a hono namespace though, because `kubectl create namespace hono` says that the namespace already exists. The next steps in the guide also fail and we can't seem to find a way to access the installation, e.g. by creating a tenant, accessing the default tenant or similar. For example, the command

```
export REGISTRY_IP=$(kubectl get service eclipse-hono-service-device-registry-ext --output="jsonpath={.status.loadBalance
r.ingress[0]['hostname','ip']}" -n hono)
```

suggested for finding the registry's IP fails with "Error from server (NotFound): services "eclipse-hono-service-device-registry-ext" not found". The same when omitting the `eclipse-` prefix.

Is there a way to find out what went wrong with our installation and how to correct it? Or how to access Hono? I have to admit we're pretty inexperienced with this kind of technology, so I apologize if we're missing something really obvious.

Comment: Did you install to a local minikube cluster?

Comment: Yes, as described [here](https://www.eclipse.org/hono/docs/deployment/create-kubernetes-cluster/#setting-up-a-local-development-environment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you haven't started a load balancer for routing requests to the services as described [here](https://www.eclipse.org/hono/docs/deployment/create-kubernetes-cluster/#setting-up-a-local-development-environment).

Comment: You're right, we missed that step and it works now. Thanks!